# How can I make sure the User can input again after entering something invalid?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class recursion2 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        char cont = 'y';
        while (cont == 'y') {

            System.out.println("Enter the number:");

            int num = scanner.nextInt();

            int factorial = fact(num);
            System.out.println("Factorial of entered number is: " + factorial);

            System.out.println("Do you want to loop again?");
            cont = input1.next().charAt(0);
        }
    }

    static int fact(int n) {
        int output;
        if (n == 1) {
            return 1;
        }

        output = fact(n - 1) * n;
        return output;
    }
}
```

The code above has 0 errors. However, Id like the code to only allow positive integers and if a user were to enter a negative integer (-20) or letters (abc) then the program would ask them to try again. I tried to use an If else statement saying if anything other than numbers > 0 would ask to try again but I could never make it work. Any tips?

Comment: You need `while` not `if`. Unlike if, which will execute at most once, a while executes repeatedly until the condition returns false (eg. ask for an input repeatedly until the input becomes valid)

Comment: This might be easiest if you make a method to input the next positive integer. You would have a loop which will work until you get valid input.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what if you did get a [clue](https://youtu.be/8DQh086cB-Q?t=148)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        char cont = 'y';
        int num;
        boolean valid;
        String strNum;
        do {
            valid = false;
            System.out.print("Enter the number: ");
            strNum = scanner.nextLine();
            if (strNum.matches("\\d+")) {
                int factorial = fact(Integer.parseInt(strNum));
                System.out.println("Factorial of entered number is: " + factorial);
                System.out.print("Do you want to loop again?");
                cont = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid entry. Please try a positive integer.");
            }
        } while (cont == 'y');
        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
    }

    static int fact(int n) {
        int output;
        if (n == 1) {
            return 1;
        }
        output = fact(n - 1) * n;
        return output;
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter the number: a
Invalid entry. Please try a positive integer.
Enter the number: 10.5
Invalid entry. Please try a positive integer.
Enter the number: -5
Invalid entry. Please try a positive integer.
Enter the number: 5
Factorial of entered number is: 120
Do you want to loop again?y
Enter the number: 3
Factorial of entered number is: 6
Do you want to loop again?n
Goodbye!
```

**Notes:**

1. Use of `do...while` is more appropriate in this case. It doesn't mean that it can not be done using `while` loop but `do...while` makes it more comprehensible.
2. Compare `scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase().charAt(0)` with `y` so that the program can continue for both `Y` and `y`.
3. `\\d+` is used to restrict a string matching with only digits and nothing else i.e. it allows only intgers.
4. `Integer::parseInt` is used to convert an integer string into `int`.
5. You do not need two `Scanner` instances.
6. Follow [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) e.g. `class recursion2` should be named as `class Recursion2` as per the naming convention.

Answer (score 2):

Use this method to validate the input.

```
public int validInput() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(1) {
        // If you wish to end the loop after a certain number of attempts
        // use a counter to exit the loop
        System.out.println("Enter the number:");
        int num = scanner.nextInt();
        if(num > 0) {
            return num;
        }
        System.out.println("Input must be greater than zero. Please try again.");
    } 
}
```

Then call this method from your code.

```
while (cont == 'y') {
  int num = validInput();

  int factorial = fact(num);
  System.out.println("Factorial of entered number is: " + factorial);

  System.out.println("Do you want to loop again?");
  cont = input1.next().charAt(0);
 }
```

You can also use this method anywhere in your project.

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you need a do-while loop where you check each time if the input is valid, and also a try-catch block inside the loop so if the Scanner throws an exception, you can catch it and ask the user to enter a positive number.

Also, you need to close the scanner at the end.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
 class recursion2{
 public static void main(String args[]){

   Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
  char cont = 'y';
 while (cont == 'y') {

  System.out.println("Enter the number:");

  int num = -1;  //Negative by default so it's invalid
  do {  //Do-while so it gets run at least once
    try {
      num = scanner.nextInt();
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) { //When it's not an int, loop again
      System.out.println("Please enter a valid input");
    }
  while (num <= 0); //Check if positive here


  int factorial = fact(num);
  System.out.println("Factorial of entered number is: " + factorial);

  System.out.println("Do you want to loop again?");
 cont = input1.next().charAt(0);
 }
 scanner.close();
 }
 static int fact(int n)
 {
   int output;
   if(n == 1){
     return 1;
   }

   output = fact(n - 1) * n;
   return output;

 }
 }
```